# Adding a resource server to an existing JSF/Spring security application

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-oauth2

Currently, we've implemented a centralized authorization server using the oauth2.0 protocols and a password flow. I will post the user, pwd, secret and clientID to the auth server endpoint, get a JWT back and be on my way.

What I currently have in this existing "client" application is some spring security boilerplate that configures traffic based on roles.

What I need to do is (I think) - When I log into the application, I will receive a token. That token is stored in the session and whenever I access a page on that application, I will either confirm the token is still good or refresh the token so that I can continue accessing secured content.

I am assuming I need to do the following:

1. Add a resource server to my existing application (@EnableResourceServer), so that traffic flows through the oauth2.0 process.
2. Configure said resource server (similar to my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter configure class), so that the token is checked
3. Keep everything else (roles, file structure, etc) the same

How do I do this with Spring? I have looked at tutorials and most everything is either same home resource and auth server solutions or has minimal explanation for how something can be configured.

Property file:

```
security.oauth2.client.client-id= clientid
security.oauth2.client.client-secret= clientsecret
security.oauth2.client.access-token-uri= http://localhost:1234/oauth/token
security.oauth2.client.user-authorization-uri= http://localhost:1234/oauth/authorize

security.oauth2.resource.service-id=res_id
security.oauth2.resource.user-info-uri= http://localhost:1234/me
security.oauth2.resource.token-info-uri= http://localhost:1234/oauth/check_token
security.oauth2.resource.token-type= Bearer
```

Current WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@ComponentScan("com.testproj")
public class CustomWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider authProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        // Authentication control
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login.xhtml**").permitAll() // All everyone to see login page
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll() // All everyone to see login page
            .antMatchers("/views/**").hasAnyAuthority("USER", "ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/javax.faces.resource/**").permitAll() // All everyone to see resources
            .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll() // All everyone to see resources
            .anyRequest().authenticated(); // Ensure any request to application is authenticated

        // Login control
        http
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login.xhtml")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .successForwardUrl("/views/home.xhtml")
                .failureUrl("/login.xhtml?error=true");

        // not needed as JSF 2.2 is implicitly protected against CSRF
        http
            .csrf().disable();
    } 

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
    }   
}
```

Custom authenticator:

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Autowired
    private AppUserDAO appUserDAO;

    private String accessTokenUri = "http://localhost:1234/oauth/token";
    private String clientId = "clientid";
    private String clientSecret = "clientsecret";

    public AccessTokenProvider userAccessTokenProvider() {
        ResourceOwnerPasswordAccessTokenProvider accessTokenProvider = new ResourceOwnerPasswordAccessTokenProvider();
        return accessTokenProvider;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

        final String username = authentication.getName();
        final String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        List<String> scopes = new ArrayList<String>();
        scopes.add("read");

        final ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails resource = new ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails();

        resource.setUsername(username);
        resource.setPassword(password);
        resource.setAccessTokenUri(accessTokenUri);
        resource.setClientId(clientId);
        resource.setClientSecret(clientSecret);
        resource.setGrantType("password");
        resource.setScope(scopes);

        // Generate an access token
        final OAuth2RestTemplate template = new OAuth2RestTemplate(resource, new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext(new DefaultAccessTokenRequest()));
        template.setAccessTokenProvider(userAccessTokenProvider());

        OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = null;

        try {
            accessToken = template.getAccessToken();
            System.out.println("Grabbed access token from " + accessTokenUri);
        }
        catch (OAuth2AccessDeniedException e) {
            if (e.getCause() instanceof ResourceAccessException) {
                final String errorMessage = String.format(
                        "While authenticating user '%s': " + "Unable to access accessTokenUri '%s'.", username,
                        accessTokenUri);
                throw new AuthenticationServiceException(errorMessage, e);
            }
            throw new BadCredentialsException(String.format("Access denied for user '%s'.", username), e);
        }
        catch (OAuth2Exception e) {
            throw new AuthenticationServiceException(
                    String.format("Unable to perform OAuth authentication for user '%s'.", username), e);
        }

        // Determine roles for user
        List<GrantedAuthority> grantList = ...

        // Create custom user for the principal
        User user = .....

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null /*dont store password*/, grantList);

        return token;
    }

    @Override
    public  boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
}
```

Resource server:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    ????
}
```

**Edit**:

So I moved my httpsecurity configuration into my resource server configuration and I get "Access Denied" when I attempt to get to the /views/home.xhtml page.

The log indicates the principal is anonymous (it wasn't like that in securityconfig)

```
Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /views/home.xhtml; Attributes: [#oauth2.throwOnError(hasAuthority('USER'))]
Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@fc4a062: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true;
```

**Edit 2**

This might be a question about what is possible with oauth2, because I'm kind of going insane.

There are 4 pieces according to the oauth specs - Auth server, resource server, client and resource owner

I guess my question is - can I actually combine the resource server and client? The resource owner would sign into my app (client), get authorization from the auth server to see their resources on the resource server/client.

I really wish I could find a good example of this - it seems so definitive and common.